# Read Teradata query into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, teradata

Has anyone found a way to read a Teradata query into a Pandas dataframe? It looks like SQLAlchemy does not have a Teradata dialect.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: https://github.com/grisaitis/sqlalchemy-teradata

Comment: Looks promising, but unfortunately it's written for Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it using `read_sql` . Below id the code snip :

```
def dqm() :
    conn_rw = create_connection()
    dataframes = []
    srcfile = open('srcqueries.sql', 'rU').read()
    querylist = srcfile.split(';')
    querylist.pop()
    for query in querylist :
        dataframes.append(pd.read_sql(query, conn_rw))
    close_connection(conn_rw)
    return dataframes,querylist
```

You can create connection as below :

```
    def create_connection():
        conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=tddb;UID=uid;PWD=pwd;QUIETMODE=YES", autocommit=True,unicode_results=True)
        return conn
```

You can check complete code here : [GitHub Link](https://github.com/minatverma/pythonWorks/blob/master/DQM.py)
Let me know if this answers your query .

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you're using pyodbc instead of sqlalchemy to create the connection, right?

Comment: Right . If you plan to install them I suggest brew package manager.

Answer (score 4):

You can use slqalchemy but you will need to install sqlalchemy-teradata too. You can do that via PIP

```
pip install sqlachemy-teradata
```

The rest of the code remains the same :)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

user, pasw, host = 'username','userpass', 'hostname'

# connect
td_engine = create_engine('teradata://{}:{}@{}:22/'.format(user,pasw,hostname))

# execute sql
query = 'select * from dbc.usersV'
result = td_engine.execute(query)

#To read your query to Pandas
df = pd.read_sql(query,td_engine)
```

Comment: Please note, as of 2019 [GitHub Issue Reference](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata/issues/86#issuecomment-541789406), sqlachemy-teradata has been superseded by [teradatasqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy/). Use this to install the necessary library `pip install teradatasqlalchemy` and then change the **create_engine** URL to be `'teradatasql://...` instead of `'teradata://...`

Answer (score 0):

You could nicely use sqlalchemy

```py
#remember to first pip install teradatasql

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib import parse

host = 'localhost'
user = 'your username'
pwd = 'your password'

#Create your sqlalchemy engine object
engine = create_engine(f"teradatasql://{host}/?user={user}&password={parse.quote(pwd)}")

#Read the table from the database into a pandas dataframe named df
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table", engine)

print(df.info())

#you are done
```