# How to create a teradata dataframe from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, teradata

I've a pandas dataframe. Is it possible to create a Teradata dataframe from pandas dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Teradata query into Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948453/read-teradata-query-into-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use copy_to_sql() function create a table in Teradata Vantage based on a teradataml DataFrame or a pandas DataFrame.

Arguments to copy_to_sql()

1. teradataml DataFrame or a pandas DataFrame
2. table name
3. schema name (optional)

   2. Create teradata dataframe from the table created in step 1

   import teradata

   import pandas as pd

   from teradataml.dataframe.copy_to import copy_to_sql

   from teradataml.context.context import *

   from teradataml.dataframe.dataframe import DataFrame

   con = create_context(host="fqdn of host", username="user", password="password")

**Assuming you have a pandas table - tbl1

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(tbl1)

copy_to_sql(df = pdf, table_name = "tbl1_td")
df = DataFrame("tbl1_td")
```