# How to pass a list of parameter to Pandas read_sql with Teradata

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way or how can I correct my syntax in order to pass a list of parameter of string into SQL query in pandas? I have the following code but it it not working
So i have a list of string and I need to pass that list parameter dynamically into the query

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd 

connection = tearadatasql.connect(host="xxx",user="xxx",password="xxx")
column_list = ['A','B','C']

query = """
            select column, row
            from table1
            where column in (%s)
        """

df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=column_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of issues:

1. The package name `teradatasql` is misspelled in your example `tearadatasql.connect`
2. You must compose the IN-predicate with the same number of question-mark parameter markers as the number of values you intend to bind.

In your example, you intend to bind the three values contained in the `column_list` variable, so you must compose the IN-predicate with three question-mark parameter markers.

Generally speaking, you should dynamically compose the IN-predicate with the number of question-mark parameter markers equal to the number of values in the parameter-value list that you will bind.

Below is a modified version of your example that corrects these two issues. I actually ran this example and verified that it works.

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd 
with teradatasql.connect(host="whomooz",user="guest",password="please") as connection:
  with connection.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("create volatile table table1 (c1 varchar(1), c2 integer) on commit preserve rows")
    cur.execute("insert into table1 values ('A', 1) ; insert into table1 values ('B', 2)")
  column_list = ['A','B','C']
  query = "select c1, c2 from table1 where c1 in ({}) order by c1".format(','.join(['?'] * len(column_list)))
  print(query)
  print("with params={}".format (column_list))
  df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=column_list)
  print(df)
```

This example produces the following output:

```
select c1, c2 from table1 where c1 in (?,?,?) order by c1
with params=['A', 'B', 'C']
  c1  c2
0  A   1
1  B   2
```

Comment: Thank you. it works and i also found another way to make it works as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should fill in the %s with some parameters

```
df = psql.read_sql(('select "column","row" from "table1" '
                 'where "column" in %(col_list)s'), connection, params={'col_list':column_list})
```

Comment: I tried to do as you suggest and it is not working. I dont know how or where I can fill my parameters with the correct syntax ?

Comment: I got new error code for the new answer:  ': params unexpected type <class 'dict'>

Comment: According to the documentation params can be a dict, can you check it maybe you have not copied completely or missed something

Comment: but i have a list, not a dict that i want to pass into the SQL

Comment: The parameter is a list but parameters can be a dictionary

Comment: have you checked  this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948453/read-teradata-query-into-pandas